# Fallback Hosting

Tags: hosting, godaddy, server-crashes

I have my site hosted on my own servers, but I am worried about potential crashes.  What I would like to do is set up a fallback website hosted through, for example: GoDaddy.  So in the event of a crash, the site (or a simplified version) would still be displayed.  Is there anyway to setup something like this?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question that encompasses many variables including technological comfort level, cost, compliance, failover types and testing frequency, RTO, RPO, etc.  One simple way would be to use a DNS failover provider likely UltraDNS to fail over to your secondary, but again I know nothing about your requirements to make a real suggestion.

Comment: yes i know. I just wanted to get a very general idea of whether or not this type of thing can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just wanted to get a very general idea of whether or not this type of thing can be done.

Yes, it can be.